# need help for If else staement in Imacro

Tags: javascript, imacros

I need code like this 
I have 2 links and one refresh link

macro start with Link 1 after 10 sec.

if it success it goes to Link 2 and stops.

If it fails it will goto refresh and then go to Link1.

Then if again problem came the link1 again goes to refresh an so on

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:A<SP>Link1<SP>custom&&TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=10

    *link1 success then directly to need to go link 2
    *  if Link fails then go to refresh and open link1 again.

    TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=CLASS:A<SP>refresh<SP>custom&&TXT:
    WAIT SECONDS=10

    TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:A<SP>Link1<SP>custom&&TXT:
    WAIT SECONDS=10

    TAG POS=2 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:A<SP>Link2<SP>custom&&TXT:
    WAIT SECONDS=10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the firefox imacros extension, you are able to use a javascript file to do the if else statement like so:

[imacros on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5C4.png)

As you can see in the previous image, there is a file called **111test.js** and **111test.iim**. In order to create an if else conditional, you first need to create the **111test.js** file and then edit it. To create it, just click the **record** button, then click **stop** right after. Then **right-click** the **#current.iim** file, and rename it to something like **111test.js** or any name you like personally, and you'll have your js file.

From there, you edit the macro as usual, but you include js code, which could look something like the following

```
iimPlay("someOtherMacro");
var bool1 = //...
var bool2 = //...

if (bool1) {
  //...
} else if (bool2) {
  //...
}
```

I hope this explains a lot of the fundamentals of how to create the situation you want. I can't create all the code for you because I don't know the technical details, but this should lead you to the right direction.